# Validate a mutated value in Nova

Tags: validation, laravel-nova

I am validating a field for tags in Nova, and each one much be unique. If the user enters `first name` it will be stored as `first-name`. However, a second entry with `first name` will pass validation because that value doesn't exist in the database. But when it's time to store it, it's also been changed to `first-name`, so it fails the `UNIQUE` constraint in the database.

I've had a look at the source code for Nova validation and it grabs a copy of all the fields before it gets the validation rules, so I can't change the data being checked within the rules themselves.

How can a validate that a value is unique after being mutated instead of before being mutated?

Comment: Can you provide the code how you are changing the value to store

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam I am using `setTagNameAttribute()` in the model, but this is a long time after Nova has done its validation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add custom middleware to Nova routes in `/nova/routes/api.php`. Since the middleware runs before the request gets to Nova, the fields can be changed at this time.

```
// Resource Management...
Route::get('/{resource}', 'ResourceIndexController@handle');
Route::get('/{resource}/count', 'ResourceCountController@show');
Route::delete('/{resource}/detach', 'ResourceDetachController@handle');
Route::put('/{resource}/restore', 'ResourceRestoreController@handle');
Route::delete('/{resource}/force', 'ResourceForceDeleteController@handle');
Route::get('/{resource}/{resourceId}', 'ResourceShowController@handle');
Route::post('/{resource}', 'ResourceStoreController@handle');
Route::put('/{resource}/{resourceId}', 'ResourceUpdateController@handle')->middleware('pre-mutate');
Route::delete('/{resource}', 'ResourceDestroyController@handle');
```

I've added middleware called `pre-mutate` to `Route::put('/{resource}/{resourceId}', 'ResourceUpdateController@handle')`.

The new middleware is added to `/app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'pre-mutate' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreMutate::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

Then the middleware is added in `app/Http/Middleware/PreMutate.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

class PreMutate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Make sure only the Articles resource is affected
        if ($request->route()->parameters()['resource'] === 'articles') {
            if ($request->request->has('tag_name')) {
                $request->request->set('tag_name',  Str::slug($request->request->get('tag_name')));
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

There is probably a nicer way to forward this request to the appropriate model to change the value correctly rather than applying the rule directly in the middleware where others won't think to look for it, but this should get you started.